# Javascript sliding (preferably jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to think of the name of the plugin (or a plugin) that slides content in (up or down).

So I have a hidden div, I click on one of the titles/header, it opens the hidden div, if I click on another header it hides the other visible div, and slides up or down the new one.

I can't think of it for some reason.. anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called an accordion and can be found in the JQuery UI.

Here is the link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're thinking of the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). If you're including the weight of the library anyway, be sure to [check out the other widgets and effects as well](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

Another note, as of the time of this answer, the current version is **jQuery UI 1.8**, you need to pair this with **jQuery 1.4**, not 1.3.2 (use jQuery UI 1.7 for that situation).